# Android Java InputDispatcher Error

Tags: java, android

I have build android app where i need to place JSON data to button. 
the code running well but when i place button list to Linear Layout I've got Inputdispatcher Error. here is my code.

```
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            Context ctx;
            ctx = getApplicationContext();
            JSONObject json = null;

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LLDestinasiWisata);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            //final JSONArray mComments = null;
            try {                               
                JSONReader jParser = new JSONReader();
                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://10.0.2.2/LimeDeMorin/"+READ_DATA_URL);
                JSONArray mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id_des = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String destin = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                    myButton = new Button(ctx);
                    myButton.setId(i);      
                    myButton.setText(destin);
                    myButton.setTextColor(Color.rgb(35, 31, 32));
                    myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_yellow));  
                    Button btn1 = ((Button) findViewById(i));
                    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View view) {                        
                            OpenDestinasiDetail odd = new OpenDestinasiDetail();
                            odd.execute(String.valueOf(myButton.getId()), myButton.getText().toString());
                        }
                    });
                    ll.addView(myButton, lp);                   
                }
                //Toast.makeText(DestinasiWisata.this, "Beep! wakeup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(DestinasiWisata.this, "ERRRRORRR="+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return json;
        }
```

how could i resolve this trouble?